# Can't make javascripts work in Rails app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm on Rails 5.1 using Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.

I am having difficulties deploying to `production` (`development` works fine, without Yarn).

Yarn is working and I have `package.json` and `node_modules`.

I have been following [Nithin's walkthrough](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/yarn-rails/). My styles are working; however, my javascript does not work.

I've tried addind `popper.js` using `//= require popper.js/dist/umd/popper`, but this hasn't helped.

None of my javascript works. For example, all dropdowns are completely dead.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

***UPDATE***

I checked out ***in development with Yarn*** and it failed. So all the files are added to the head, but do not work!

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the Bootstrap working! I removed it with `yarn remove bootstrap` and reinstalled it with `yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6`

Then I added `//= require tether/dist/js/tether` to application.js right upon `//= require bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap`

Also I removed `//= require popper.js/dist/umd/popper` cause the alpha version seems to be working fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your format is wrong here:

```
\\= require popper.js/dist/umd/popper
```

Check you're using the correct folder for `popper.js`, and -- if that's correct --
 use the following format:

```
//= require popper.js/dist/umd/popper
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I did a typo in my question, the code is OK.